# JavaFX WebView :sending a String from javafx to js webview

Tags: javascript, java, javafx, webview, leaflet

I currently render a web page using `WebEngine`. I'd like to send a `String` from the Java method to `WebView` to show it in the maps popup (Leaflet) .

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
 webEngine.executeScript("addpopup(" + new_val.getDescription() + "," + new_val.getLatitude() + "," + new_val.getLongitude() + ")");
```

Related JavaScript code:

```
function addpopup(desc,lan,lat){
    var popup = L.popup().setLatLng([lan, lat]).setContent(desc).openOn(map);
}
```

It works without the description parameter.

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're missing quotes around `new_val.getDescription()`:

```
webEngine.executeScript("addpopup('" + new_val.getDescription() + "'," 
     + new_val.getLatitude() + "," + new_val.getLongitude() + ")");
```